# A point of the closed unit ball is the midpoint of two points of the unit sphere

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(E, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ be a real normed space of dimension $n \ge 2$. Any point of the closed unit ball $B$ is the midpoint of two points of the unit sphere $S$. *Note: $E$ is not supposed to be Euclidean, and therefore $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is whatever norm.*

**My attempts**

I investigated a proof by contradiction and take $x \in B$. I suppose that $x \neq 0$, as the result is trivial in that case: $0$ is the midpoint of any diameter of $S$. I consider the map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & E \times E & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & (y_1,y_2) & \longmapsto & \left\lVert\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} - x\right\rVert \end{array}$$

$f$ is continuous for whatever norm equips $E \times E$ and all those norms are equivalent as $E$ is supposed to have a finite dimension. $S \times S$ is a compact subset of $E \times E$, again because the dimension of $E$ is finite. Therefore $f$ attains its minimum in $S \times S$ at let say $(x_1,x_2)$. If the minimum value is equal to zero, we're done. So I suppose that $f(x_1,x_2) \gt 0$, and I have to seek a contradiction. For this, I try to find $(x_1 + \epsilon_1, x_2+\epsilon_2) \in S \times S$ "close to $(x_1,x_2)$" such that $f(x_1 + \epsilon_1, x_2+\epsilon_2) \lt f(x_1,x_2)$... without much result so far. Any good idea?

*Subsidiary question: does the result also hold for infinite dimensional spaces $E$?*

Comment: This [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359666) seems to have the answer (and for all convex closed bounded sets rather than just the unit ball) for finite-dimensional vector spaces via the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. I have not found anything for the infinite-dimensional case, nor anything that'd be simpler/more elementary for the unit ball specifically.

Comment: The infinite-dimensional case follows immediately from the finite-dimensional case by taking a finite-dimensional subspace containing $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey If I follow you, proving the result for $n=2$ will be sufficient.

Comment: Oh I see now. Yes $n = 2$ would suffice, because as Eric said, you can take any $y$ linearly independent from $x$ and restrict yourself to $V := \operatorname{span}(x,y)$. The restriction of the norm to $V$ is still a norm, and the unit sphere for that norm in $V$, say $S_V$ is just $S_V = S \cap V$. So if the result is true for $n = 2$ and as such in $V$, then you'll have $x$ as the midpoint of points in $S_V \subset S$.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for the heads up. In fact this question comes from problems given to strong undergrade students in France where Borsuk-Ulam theorem is not supposed to be known. So I suspect that a more elementary proof can be found. Maybe it will mimic Borsuk-Ulam though.

Comment: In the answer that you now deleted, what you showed is that $x$ is on the bisector of the segment $[-a,a]$ for $a$ on the sphere. But I think this might be workable if you can then manage to prove (rigorously) that the parallel to $[-a,a]$ passing by $x$ meets the circle (translating things correctly with a general norm and not the euclidian one only of course).

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for your comment! I realized it and I'm working to update the proof.

Comment: @BrunoB Finally found something using basic results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*After various attempts, I was finally able to find an elementary and self contained proof.*

Let $x \in B$ and consider the map:

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
g : & E & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & y & \longmapsto & \lVert 2x-y \rVert
\end{array}$$

$g$ is continuous. As the dimension of $E$ is supposed to be greater or equal to $2$, $S$ is connected (it is path-connected). Notice that

$$g\left(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert }\right) \le 1 \le g\left(-\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert }\right)$$

The image of $S$ under $g$ is an interval that contains $1$. Therefore, it exists $a \in S$ such that $g(a) = 1$. $a$ and $2x-a$ belong to $S$ and their midpoint is $x$. This allows to conclude to the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an idea to complete your proof, but here is an alternative

First, as noted in the comments that it is enough to consider the case $n = 2$ (even without the assumption that $E$ is finite dimensional). Indeed, for $E$ of arbitrary dimension $n \ge 2$ and $x$ in the closed unit ball of $E$, we can consider the two dimensional subspace $E_{x,y} = \operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$ for any $y \in E$ which is linearly independent with $x$. If we equip $E_{x,y}$ with the norm induced by $E$ then $x$ is in the closed unit ball of $E_{x,y}$ and any two points on the unit sphere of $E_{x,y}$ are also points on the unit sphere of $E$.

Therefore I can assume without loss of generality that $E = \mathbb{R}^2$ (but not necessarily with the Euclidean norm). Let $x \in B$ and define $\lambda_\pm(\theta) = \inf\{\lambda: \|x \pm \lambda A_\theta e \| = 1\}$ where $A_\theta$ is the rotation matrix by angle $\theta$ and $e$ is an arbitrary norm $1$ vector. Then $x$ is the midpoint of the line connecting $x + \lambda_+(\theta)$ and $x - \lambda_-(\theta)$ if and only if $\lambda_+(\theta) = \lambda_-(\theta)$. This motivates us to consider $g(\theta) = \lambda_+(\theta) - \lambda_-(\theta)$. Note that $\lambda_\pm(\theta + \pi) = \lambda_\mp(\theta)$ so that $g(\theta + \pi) = - g(\theta)$ which implies that if $g$ takes non-zero values then it takes both positive and negative values. Therefore by the intermediate value theorem, it suffices to check that $g$ is continuous.

For this, it is enough to realise that $\lambda_\pm(\theta) = p_{B - x}(\pm A_\theta e)$ where $p_K$ denotes the [Minkowski Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) of $K$. Both $A_\theta$ and the Minkowski functional are continuous (where for the latter claim we use that $x \in B$: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173020/minkowski-functional-p-e-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-0-in-e0-textinte) for a proof) so that the result follows.