Separation Theorem for Weak Topology - Weak topology is completely regular
I am interested in proving a separation theorem in weak topology setting.
Let $X$ be a normed space and let $C \subset X$ be a weakly closed subset of $X$. Set $x_0\in X\setminus C$. Prove there exists a weakly continuous function (not neccesarily lineal such that) $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(C)=1$.
The proof is supposed to be 'easy' but how do I even start?
I have considered trying Hahn-Banach theorem and considering $$f(x)=\dfrac{d(x,x_0)}{d(x,x_0)+d(x,C)}$$ but I am unable to finish the proof.
Could you please help me in this proof?
Thanks in advance!

Replacing $C$ with $C-x_0$ you may assume that $x_0=0$. Since the weak topology is regular, there exist disjoint weakly open subset $U,V$  such that $0 \in U $ and $C \subset V$. We may assume that $U$ is convex and absorbing (otherwise we can shrink $U$ accordingly). Let $p_U$ be the Minkowski functional of $U$. Then $p_U(0) =0$ and $p_U\ge 1$ on $U^c$. Take $f=\min\{1,p_U\}$. Then $f(0) = 0 $ and $f=1$ on $C$.

This is true for any locally convex TVS. In fact, it is true for every topological group

$C$ was not assumed to be convex.

@Jochen I do not think I used that $C$ is convex, only that $U$ is. Am I wrong? Perhaps $V$ is not convex but that is not a problem

Every uniform space (hence, in particular, every topological group) is completely regular.

But the Minkoski fucntional is not weakly continuous isn't it?

It is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173020/minkowski-functional-p-e-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-0-in-e0-textinte
